# php warning when trying to set a bit in a string/chr

Tags: php, bit

I have used the following code to set a bit. This has been working fine in php5.

```
function setbit($pos) {
    return (1 << $pos);  
}
$test = chr(0);
$test += setbit(2);
print_r($test);
//result 4
```

Since upgrading to php7 now I get an error Warning: A non-numeric value encountered. The output of $test is still outputting as 4, which is correct.

I understand the error. It is because $test is a string and my setbit function is returning an integer.
Like I said this worked fine in php5 but now won't work in php7.

$test has to stay a string as I do some string operations later in the code
eg

```
$test = chr(3);
```

I know I could just turn off the warning in php_ini, but I would rather solve the problem than hide it.
Is there a way to make this work in php7 without turning off the warning?

Comment: on PHP7.2 the code works. A warning != error (though of course, it's much better to have no warnings/notices/errors)

Comment: I know it is a warning, but I want to rewrite it so that there is no warning, if possible

Comment: [concat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) instead of trying to do maths

Comment: I am trying to set the bit in $test. I don't think concat can do that. I am also setting other bits after this, so I can't use equals or concat

Comment: then typecast it before trying to do maths - or treat `$test` as 0 instead of `chr(0);`

Comment: tried casting and it didn't work. $test has to be a chr as it is being written to a binary file. It is storing bytes which is why I have to do some bit shifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to set a bit in a character is to create a mask and then use the bit operator | to associate the character with the mask.

```
 /* 
  * set a bit to first char of string $str
  * @param string $str
  * @param $bitPos 0..7
  * @return string, false if error
  */  
  function setBit($str, $bitPos){
    if($bitPos < 0 OR $bitPos > 7) return false;
    return $str |= chr(1<<$bitPos);
  }
```

Examples for use

```
$test = chr(0);
$test = setBit($test,0);
//or $test = setBit(chr(0),0);
echo bin2hex($test)."<br>\n";  //01

$test = setBit($test,1);
echo bin2hex($test)."<br>\n";  //03
```

Comment: Had to switch projects. give me a couple of days and I will test this out